# Automatic scroll to bottom of page doesnt work [javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm attempting to create a terminal/console on my website. I found the functions for scrolling down on a page using javascript, which are `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` and `window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".fakeScreen").scrollHeight)`. However, I can make neither of them work. I put them on different places; at the bottom of my `writeText` function and at each of my functions, however none worked.

[image: Showcase]

Attempt one (writeText function):

```
function writeText(data) {
    output.innerHTML += `${data}<br>`;
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Attempt two (at each of my functions):

```
function whoami() {
    writeText(`
<br>
hi! i'm gxzs, bla bla bla..
<br>`)
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Css (terminal, scrollbar)

```css
.terminalScreen {
    background-color: #282828;
    opacity: 90%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.terminalScreen::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;              
}

.terminalScreen::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #282828;        
}

.terminalScreen::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #141414;    
    border-radius: 15px;       
    border: 3px solid #282828;  
}
.terminalScreen .output {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your `window` variable targets the element which has the scrollbar inside the terminal rather its the `window` variable of the browser. Try something like this: `ElementWithScrollbarInTheTerminal.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)`. ([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo))

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Thanks, I understand what's happening and how it works now. But I still don't really know what element to specify. I added the part of my css for reference.

Comment: Try this: `document.querySelector(".terminalScreen").scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)`. Also it will be better if you include the whole code so we can debug, its bit hard to guess like this.

Comment: That's great, Just added the comments as an answer just for future reference for others.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object you are targeting is the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object exposed by the browser and not the terminal window.

To scroll the terminal scrollbar you need to target the element with the scrollbar inside the terminal. Like this:

```js
document.querySelector(".terminalScreen").scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
```